# Only run integration test when deploying from staging to production

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, integration-testing, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have 3 main branches in my gitlab project: `dev` , `staging`, `production`. I'm using postman newman for integration testing like this in `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
postman_tests:
    stage: postman_tests
    image: 
        name: postman/newman_alpine33
        entrypoint: [""] 
    only:
      - merge_requests
    script:
        - newman --version
        - newman run https://api.getpostman.com/collections/zzz?apikey=zzz  --environment https://api.getpostman.com/environments/xxx?apikey=xxxx
```

this script only run in merge request approval process from dev to staging , or staging to production. The problem is i need to only run this postman newman test when  the process of merge request approval from staging to production, how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using the 'advanced' only/except settings in combination with supplied environment variables:

```
postman_tests:
    stage: postman_tests
    image: 
        name: postman/newman_alpine33
        entrypoint: [""] 
    only:
      refs:
        - merge_requests
      variables:
        - $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME == "staging"
        - $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "production"
    script:
        - newman --version
        - newman run https://api.getpostman.com/collections/zzz?apikey=zzz  --environment https://api.getpostman.com/environments/xxx?apikey=xxxx
```

For a full list of predefined environment variables you can go [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html#variables-reference)

Comment: i got this following [error](https://ibb.co/2gjncpG)  in my pipeline, it said **variables config should be a hash of key value pairs**

Comment: The error seems to point to another job named 'integration_tests'. Have you copied my example above?

Comment: @secustoer yes, i just rename my postman_tests to integration_tests , so i only copy the variables part

Comment: to copy only the variables part is not enough, you can't mix 'simple' and 'advanced' configuration. See the added `refs` object.

Comment: I have reproduced the error. The `refs` block and the `variables` block needs to have the same indentation!

Comment: @blue If this solved your issue, please mark the question as solved.